# OID of wireless MAC Whitelist

Tags: snmp, mib

I try to read and write the MAC white-list of a wireless Hotspot.
I try to be able to configure such a wireless access point (and multiple devices) with a command line or a batch file without logging into the web interface of every single hotspot.

I am writing my tool in Java using SNMP4J.

My testing device is a Funkwerk bintec w2002 (Teldata GmbH).

Does anyone know where I can get the OID of the MAC white-list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the appropriate MIB file(s) for the hotspot. The MIB files specify which objects can be polled, and what their OIDs are. If the vendor publishes the MIB files on their web site, you're in luck. Otherwise, try the customer support.

If you can't find the MIB files, you can try doing an SNMP walk of the hotspot. That will give you all the data, but you won't know what the OIDs mean (unless it's a standard MIB which you or your tools are familiar with). Anyway, a MAC address is pretty distinctive so you should be able to spot it.

A suitable command-line tool for doing the SNMP walk would be the net-snmp cli suite, with the "snmpwalk" command. Their web site (http://www.net-snmp.org/) can also give you some prods in the right direction when it comes to a system administrator's use of SNMP.

If you're really lucky, the MIB objects are writable so you could set them using the snmpset command.

Comment: I think we had the same Ideas. I just looked at the developers web site and found a zip with all tables explained. half an hour of searching later did I find the right MIB: it is called wlanACLTable and has the OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.272.4.46.8.1 .